# Generate Correlated Normals

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, correlation, monte-carlo

I want to generate normals $X,Y,Z$ with the correlation matrix $R$ but with means $0, 1, 2$ and variances $4, 16, 25$ respectively.

How can I do this?
Is it possible to apply Cholesky?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution

Comment: Do  you want to draw a sample from a population with the specified means, variances, and covariances, or do you want the specified numbers to be the exact means, variances, and covariances in the sample?  The latter is more challenging but perfectly doable. $\qquad$

Comment: The latter, I am vaguely aware of how to solve the former. I am having a lot of trouble understanding how exactly Cholesky works and what it means to generate a correlated variable, though.